# What does the following mean wrt. binary representations of signed types in C language?

Tags: c, signed

> C allows three different sign representations:
>
> - Sign and magnitude
> - Ones’ complement
> - Two’s complement
>
> The first two nowadays probably only have historical or exotic relevance: for sign and magnitude, the magnitude is taken as positive values, and the sign bit simply specifies that there is a minus sign. Ones’ complement takes the corresponding positive value and
> complements all bits. **Both representations have the disadvantage that two values evaluate to 0: there is a positive and a negative 0.**

*Source: Modern C, Jens Gustedt*

Question: What's wrong with "two values evaluating to zero" according to the last statement (in bold)?

Comment: For a signed integer (and for floats as well), the left most bit is reserved for the sign bit. So, `1000......0000` and `0000......0000`, both are zero but the former has the sign bit turned on, meaning "negative."

Comment: You have 256 possible numbers for a 8 bit integer. If you have a number twice, you have only 255 possible numbers. E.g., `-128` to `127` for 2s complement and `-127` to `127` for the other.

Comment: What's wrong ... ? Well, aside from the fact that you're 'wasting' one possible representation (trivial), code may fail in a bit-comparison of two zero values, if they have different representations.

Comment: Perhaps ask [@Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt)?

Comment: @AdrianMole [you're 'wasting' one possible representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362250/what-does-the-following-mean-wrt-binary-representations-of-signed-types-in-c-la/70362464#comment124379190_70362250) argument applies to common _floating point_ too.  2's complement has its trouble too with `-INT_MAX != INT_MIN`.  I do not see non-2's complement as _wrong_ as much as it lost to 2's complement over the years as the weaker approach.

Comment: @chux - Yeah - the loss of 'space' for one value is not significant (like, for 32- or 64-bit integers), which is why I called it "trivial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's wrong with "two values evaluating to zero" according to the last statement (in bold)?

**Example: strings**

When `char` is *signed*, what is wrong with this code if integer encoding is not 2's complement?

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {
  const char *t = s;
  while (*t) {
    t++;
  }
  return t - s;
}
```

> `while (*t)` stops on both +0 and -0, when it should stop only on +0.

> **String handling `<string.h>`** For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).  C17dr 7.24.1 3

> Should have used `const unsigned char *t = s;`.  With 2's complement, make no difference either way.

> Basic problem is that there are times when code should distinguish +0 from -0, but common code only look at the *value*, and not the sign of an *signed* integer when it is 0.

---

[C2x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features) is expected to require 2's complement.

Corner *benefits* of non-2's complement: *Symmetric* positive and negative ranges.
`abs(i)` value for all `i`.  `-i` valid for all `i`.  `-1/x` is never a problem for non-zero `x`.

Comment: Note that sample code may be contrived but serves to illustrate.  I'd expect `char` is _unsigned_ with rare non-2's complement implementations.

Comment: Note that binary floating point effectively encodes via  _sign-magnitude_ for the sign and significant.